# How to sort a collection of objects in an Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a collection objects in an array,

```
[{A:2, B:2},{A:2, B:3},{A:1, B: 2}, {A:1, B:1}]
```

I would like to have a sort result of property A then property B. Therefore, as a result it should be:

```
[{A:1, B:1}, {A:1, B:2}, {A:2, B:2}, {A:2, B:3}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a JSON array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-a-json-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort by A then by B. This sort works, because if `A == A` then `A - A` is `0`. And `0 || anything` is always `anything`. So it compares `A` then differs to `B` is `A's are equal.`

```
var list = [{A:2, B:2},{A:2, B:3},{A:1, B: 2}, {A:1, B:1}];
list.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.A - b.A || a.B - b.B
})
```

Using fully cross browser [**sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and the benefits of lazy evaluation

Comment: Nice edit of your original post which didn't accomplish the desired result (which is why I wrote my answer).

Answer (score 3):

You use a custom sort callback that first compares the A values and then, if those are equal uses the B values, thus creating primary and secondary keys for the sort:

```
var collection = [{A:2, B:2},{A:2, B:3},{A:1, B: 2}, {A:1, B:1}];

collection.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.A != b.A) {
        return(a.A - b.a);
    } else {
        return(a.B - b.B);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try following code

```
[{A:2, B:2},{A:2, B:3},{A:1, B: 2}, {A:1, B:1}]
.sort(function(a, b) { return (a.A< b.A) ? -1 : (a.A> b.A) ? 1 : 0 })
.sort(function(a, b) { return (a.B< b.B) ? -1 : (a.B> b.B) ? 1 : 0 });
```